# NHibernate not updating child entity

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am facing a problem when trying to update a child item in Parent class

```
public class Parent
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Child> MyChildren { get; set; }
    }
    public class Child
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Parent MyParent { get; set; }
    }
```

What i do is to take one item of the MyChildren list and modify it, but when calling SaveOrUpdate Method from Session MyClildren  is not being saved.

Note: if other fields in parent are modified it get updated in DB.

Update:

```
<class name="Parent" table="Parent" lazy="true">
    <id name="id" column="ID" type="int">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

      <bag cascade="all" lazy="true" name="MyChildren">
        <key column="ID"/>
        <one-to-many class="SND.Domain.Model.Child" />
      </bag>
</class>

<class name="Child" table="Child" lazy="true">
    <id name="id" column="ID" type="int">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <!-- Here i have another reference -->
     <many-to-one name="AnotherEntity" class="SND.Domain.Model.AnotherEntity" column="entity_ID"/>

    <property name="Name" column="Name" type="string" not-null="false" />
</class>
```

Thanks,
Pedro

Comment: Could you please add the mapping files or mapping code for NHibernate to your question? There is not enough to go on here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your mapping file, but do you have the cascade attribute on your child collection set in the parent mapping file?

Answer (score 0):

It's a mapping trouble I think, try this :

```
<bag  generic="true" cascade="all" inverse="false" name="MyChildren">
    <key column="ID"/>
    <one-to-many class="SND.Domain.Model.Child" />
</bag>
```

**Update1**

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{

    session.SaveOrUpdate( ... );
    tx.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Do you use a transaction ? if yes do you commit ? see update1